# Priority function for Priority Queue in Python

Tags: java, python-2.7, priority-queue

How would I write the following Java PriorityQueue in Python?

```
PriorityQueue<Integer[]> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer[]>(11,
        new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
          public int compare(Integer[] A, Integer[] B) {
            return A[0] < B[0] ? -1 : 1;
          }
        });
```

I got as far as

```
from Queue import PriorityQueue
def my_method(self):
  pq = # I got stuck here since I need to include "comparator"
```

I have looked through many examples such as [Creating a python priority Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311480/creating-a-python-priority-queue) but they don't seem to be defining a `priorty function` or `comparator` of some sort.

Comment: if A.pulp == B.pulp, you should return 0

Comment: Is this another pathetic down-vote? Is this from the guy whose response got down-voted so that he deleted his response. I didn't down-vote your response -- although I should have since it was way off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to put `(A.pulp, A)` as the values in your priority queue. That way, it will use tuple comparisons to compare `pulp` values first.

Another option is to implement `__cmp__` (or define `__lt__` and `__eq__` and use `functools.total_ordering`) on your class to do the necessary comparisons. This assumes you don't have some other comparison function in place already.

Comment: Can you show an example or a link of how I would write the PriorityQueue with the comparison function?

Comment: In the second case you'd be writing the class with the comparison function.

Comment: What if `A` was actually a list and `A.pulp` was the first element of the list, as in `A=[5,1,7,9,2]`. How should `pq.put(A[0],A)` work? It does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: Put a tuple: `pq.put((A[0], A))`

Comment: instead of `(A.pulp, A)` what actually works is `([A.pulp, A])`